# jackson xml to pojo - child element as string

Tags: java, jackson, pojo

I am doing a code to parse XML then convert as POJO. I am using jackson..

I want to parse child elemnt as String. How can I do that?

for example:

```
<content>
 <template>
       <value>
        <property>
        </property>
     </value> 
 </template>
 <template>
     <value>
        <property>
        </property>
     </value> 
 </template>
</content>
```

My POJO should be:

```
class Content {
  List<Template> template;
}
class Template {
    String allString;
}
```

I want to put the child element of template as all string.. so the value of

```
allString = "<value>
        <property>
        </property>
     </value>";
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @Clijsters Welcome to you too.  Could you be more specific what is wrong with the question?

Comment: @FlorianF you missed your current code. Your problem description could be more accurate, and you have typos in your question.